# Any Firefox plugin to display memory usage of each tab?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Just wondering if there is any Firefox plugin to display memory usage of each tab?

Just some website just eats up so much memory so fast when I open it in a new tab, for example some canvas loading sequences of images just to play an animation, stuff like that totally freeze my browser big time.